# Selecting one chart at a time using drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts

I am using javascript and jqplot to plot multiple charts based on the data on my JSON file. I have been able to do that but now I want to put a drop down list which should be linked with my chart container. Meaning, selecting a particular option will show chart for that container only. My code is shown below. Here I want to show for example only "chart1" when I select "area1". Can anyone please help me achieving this. My code also contains a js function for selecting a particular chart but when I select area1 all the charts hide and same goes for all the options. My code is as below:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            $('div:not(#div' + val + ')').slideUp();
            $('#div' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<select>
<option value="">Select an Area</option>
<option value="1">Area1</option>
<option value="2">Area2</option>
<option value="3">Area3</option>
<option value="3">Area4</option>
<option value="3">Not Defined Area</option>
</select>
<div id="chart1" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart2" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart3" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart4" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart5" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
```

Comment: Change this 

    $('div:not(#chart' + val + ')').slideUp();
    $('#chart' + val).slideDown();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val!="") {
            //change div with chart
            $('div:not(#chart' + val + ')').slideUp();
            //slide down selected one
            $('#chart' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<select>
<option value="">Select an Area</option>
<option value="1">Area1</option>
<option value="2">Area2</option>
<option value="3">Area3</option>
<option value="3">Area4</option>
<option value="3">Not Defined Area</option>
</select>
<div id="chart1"  style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart2"  style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart3"  style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart4"  style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
<div id="chart5"  style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
```

Comment: it partially works, the issue are:

1. when no area is selected, it shows all the 5 graphs....it should not show any graph
2. When we select an option it shows the graph without the title and without the value and lebel of axes.

Comment: do $('div').slideDown(); to $('div').slideup(); on else.

Comment: it partially works, the issue are:

1. when no area is selected, it shows all the 5 graphs....it should not show any graph
2. When we select an option it shows the graph without the title and without the value and lebel of axes.
3. When I select Area4, it shows graph of area 3, graph of area4 is never shown.
4. Also, when I select the 5th Option "Not Defined Area", it shows graph for area 3.

Comment: changing else statement doesn't make any difference though

Comment: Got resolved issue 3 and 4...............the option value was 3 by mistake for the last 3 tags. Now we are left with top 2 issues

Comment: I cant see the code you just posted: my updated code is:

JavaScript:

$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val) {
            //change div with chart
            $('div:not(#chart' + val + ')').slideUp();
            //slide down selected one
            $('#chart' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideUp();
        }
    });
});

Comment: Only you have to make else if(val==1) then do/// else if(val==2) then do// so on.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97757/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-govind).

Comment: Tried this:

$(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        
        if (val!="") {
            //change div with chart
            $('div:not(#chart' + val + ')').slideUp();
            //slide down selected one
            $('#chart' + val).slideDown();
        } else {
            $('div').slideUp();
        }
    });
});

However no change